# Android support all screen sizes: UIs stretches in Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android-layout, android

In my Android application I have included the followings in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

 <supports-screens 
     android:largeScreens="true" 
     android:normalScreens="true" 
     android:smallScreens="true" 
     android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Also under the Res folder(UI Design), I have designed separate UIs for the following screen sizes.

```
layout
layout-large
layout-small
```

So it works really fine, But in the **Samsung Galaxy Note** which has a slightly bigger screen(5.3 inches), my UI elements gets stretch and part of it goes beyond the screen limit and become not accesible.

According to the [SUPPORTING MULTIPLE SCREENS POST BY ANDROID](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range), this phone should work fine using the `layout-large` layout resourses and the `drawable-xhdpi` image resources.

Can't figureout what exacly happens. Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks inadvance...!!!!

**Edits**

Just to test I created another extra set of UIs under `layout-large-xhdpi` named folder under Res folder as well. So when I test it takes the UIs from this folder but still UI elements Go beyond the screen limit. Also all the width amounts have assigned with `dp` units.

=== Some Screen shots to explain the problem Situation  ===

Following is a screenshot of how it looks`(layout-large-xhdpi)` in the Graphical layout while designing

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings" />       

</LinearLayout>
```

When it runs it just stretches (following screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Screenshots explaining what you mean might help here.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. I just added some screenshots in the edits part in the question to explain the situation. Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Account" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Settings" />       

</LinearLayout>
```

As per the guidelines given by Google, you should avoid using hardcoded pixels in your layout.

refer to this link for more details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hi mudit, Thanks. But even I can use it here and work it done, I can't use the android:layout_weight property in RelativeLayouts.

Comment: yes that is true. In relative layouts, you can alignParent attributes and to_left or to_Right attributes for creating such layouts. Also please accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: HI Mudit, Yes alignParent is Ok just to place the elements. Still no way to assign width for them. In my post if it is a relative layout then can't add two buttons of same width. Then I will have to add a lenier layout within a relative layout. So its going to be too many layouts within it. Isn't there any way to achieve this in relative layouts. If So then My problem will solve. Thanks Mudit.

Comment: Every layout has 1-2 limitations. While relative layout provides you a facility to align views in all dimensions, it doesnt have a way to define weight type parameters like linear layout. So atleast for this type of scenario, you have to use a linear layout.

Comment: Hi Mudit, Still I can't understand why it does not get exact width as I have assign values in DP units and not Px. In android Suppot multiple Screens POST Under the "Best Practices" first point it clearly says use DP units to avoid happen that. I think I am doing some mistake, and thats why this problem only occurs in Samsung Galaxy Note and not anywhere alse.

Comment: ok.. i will try to run your XML and will let you know my finding whenever i get time.